# Include ERB delimiters inside of a string in an ERB block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am working on a style guide which displays the code, as well as the output. It is currently structured so that the code only needs to be described once, and is displayed in both its raw and interpreted versions, like so:

```
<% code = <<PLACE_THE_EXAMPLE_CODE_BETWEEN_THESE_TWO_LINES_EXACTLY_AS_YOU_WANT_IT_TO_APPEAR
<div>
  #{ image_tag 'image.png' }
</div>  
PLACE_THE_EXAMPLE_CODE_BETWEEN_THESE_TWO_LINES_EXACTLY_AS_YOU_WANT_IT_TO_APPEAR
%>

<%= raw code %>
<%= content_tag :pre, code, class: "prettyprint linenums" %>
```

This is great, and fairly easy to maintain. The problem comes in with the rails helpers, like `image_tag` in the above example. The view example correctly displays an image in a div, and the code example displays the relevant HTML. In this case, the relevant HTML includes an anchor tag - the results of the `image_tag` method, not the call itself.

I would prefer the code examples to display the helper methods, rather that their results. I am able to make this work by specifying the example code in a file, and either rendering or reading the file. I would prefer to make this work by specifying the code in a variable, as above, but I can't seem to get an ERB delimiter to work inside of a string inside of an erb block. Even the simplest case of `<% foo = '<%= bar %>' %>` doesn't work at all. I've tried playing with the syntax (`<%% %%>` and `% %` for example), using details from the [official documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html), without much success.

The only information I could find on the matter is [here](http://markmail.org/message/gpz5bpqvbclogo7a), using `<%= "<" + "%=" %> link_to <%= image.css_tag.humanize %> <%= "%" + ">" %> %>`, which does not work in this use case (if at all).

So, is there a way to specify a string that contains a ERB end-delimiter (`%>`) in an ERB string, or am I stuck using the slightly clunkier file-read method? Thanks!

**Edit:**

What I would like to end up with is a working version of this:

```
<%# Idealized code - does not work %>
<% code = <<PLACE_THE_EXAMPLE_CODE_BETWEEN_THESE_TWO_LINES_EXACTLY_AS_YOU_WANT_IT_TO_APPEAR
<div>
  <% image_tag 'image.png' %>
</div>  
PLACE_THE_EXAMPLE_CODE_BETWEEN_THESE_TWO_LINES_EXACTLY_AS_YOU_WANT_IT_TO_APPEAR
%>
```

So that `<%= raw code %>` would (continue to) output:

```
<div>
  <img src="/images/image.png" alt="Image" />
</div>
```

And `<%= content_tag :pre, code, class: "prettyprint linenums" %>` would output:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
  <div>
    <% image_tag 'image.png' %>
  </div>  
</pre>
```

Instead of what it currently does when using a variable, which is:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums">
  <div>
    <img src="/images/image.png" alt="Image" />
  </div>
</pre>
```

I want users to be able to copy the code example and paste it into a new view, without having to translate HTML back into the helpers that produce them. I think what I basically need is an alternative ERB delimiter, in the same way that `'` and `"` (or even `%q{}`) vary for strings. It seems that even though the final ERB delimiter is occurring inside of a string, it is being actually processed as the end of the block. The simplest case of `<% foo = '<%= bar %>' %>` demonstrates somewhat what I want to accomplish. In a generator, you might use `<% foo = '<%%= bar %>' %>` (or something similar), to tell it not to process as ERB right then and there. This all works fine when reading from a file, or even in a pure rb file (like a helper), but it makes the most sense to put it in the view, in this case, as it is intended to be easily manipulated by our designers.

Comment: So the problem isn't just interpolation, you have an ERB-within-ERB problem mixed in too?

Comment: Yeah, I can get the interpolation to go the way I need it to, just not by my preferred method. I can't find any way to get ERB within ERB, using any kind of syntax. I actually kind of thought that the heredoc might be a little more forgiving than a traditional single line string, but it seems that ERB is pretty aggressive about honoring any `%>` that it comes across...

Comment: You can change the delimiters with erubis (see [`-p pattern`](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.07.html#command-usage)) so there should be a way to do it from within Rails. I'll poke around a bit more and see what I can find (unless someone else gets to it first).

Comment: Right on - thank you! It does seem very odd that there would not be an alternate delimiter syntax, as there is for almost everything else. I'll be darned if I could figure it out, from research or playing around (so far), however.

Comment: I think I have a strategy that should work without too much pain. Have a look at my update and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Wow, very interesting - this looks promising. I'm gonna give this a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, your real problem is that heredocs behave like double quotes as far as interpolation is concerned. So all you need is a quoting mechanism that behaves like single quotes. Ruby has lots of string quoting mechanisms, in particular we have `%q{...}`:

```
<% code = %q{
<div>
  #{ image_tag 'image.png' }
</div>  
} %>
```

You can use other delimiters if you'd like: `%q|...|`, `%q(...)`, etc. There's still a change of course but at least you don't have to worry about interpolation problems.

If you really want to use a heredoc, you can specify the [heredoc terminator with quotes](http://ruby-doc.org//docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UD) and the corresponding quoting style will apply to the content:

```
<% code = <<'PLACE_THE_EXAMPLE_CODE_BETWEEN_THESE_TWO_LINES_EXACTLY_AS_YOU_WANT_IT_TO_APPEAR'
<div>
  #{ image_tag 'image.png' }
</div>  
PLACE_THE_EXAMPLE_CODE_BETWEEN_THESE_TWO_LINES_EXACTLY_AS_YOU_WANT_IT_TO_APPEAR
%>
```

The single quotes in `<<'PLACE...'` specify that single quoting rules (i.e. no interpolation) apply to the heredoc's content.

---

Of course none of that stuff will work with embedded ERB like this:

```
<% code = %q{
<div>
  <% ... %>
</div>  
} %>
```

because the ERB parser will see the first `%>` as the closing delimiter for the outer `<% code...` part. Fear not, I think I have a plan that will work without involving gross hacks or too much work.

**Some preliminaries**:

- Rails uses [Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/) for ERB processing.
- Erubis allows you to [change the delimiters with the `:pattern` option](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.02.html#tut-pattern) to its constructor.
- Rails uses [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) and [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) to handle the template processing pipeline, these allow you to make the right things happen to `pancakes.js.coffee.erb` in the right order.

Using the above you can add your own template format that is ERB with a different delimiter and you can have Rails use this new format to handle your "special" sections before the normal ERB processing can make a mess of things.

First you need to hook up Tilt. If you have a look at `lib/tilt/erb.rb` in your Tilt installation, you'll see the Erubis stuff in `Tilt::ErubisTemplate` at the bottom. You should be able to subclass `Tilt::ErubisTemplate` and provide a `prepare` override that adds, say, a `:pattern => '<!--% %-->'` option and punts to the superclass. Then register this with Tilt and Sprockets in a Rails initializer with something like this:

```
Tilt.register(Your::Template::Subclass, 'klerb') # "kl" for "kludge" :)
Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.klerb', Your::Template::Subclass)
```

Now your application should be able to handle `.klerb` files with `<!--% ... %-->` as the template delimiters. And you can also chain your klerb with erb using names like `pancakes.html.erb.klerb` and the file will go through klerb before the ERB; this means that templates like this (in a file called `whatever.html.erb.klerb`):

```
<!--% code = <<PLACE_THE_EXAMPLE_CODE_BETWEEN_THESE_TWO_LINES_EXACTLY_AS_YOU_WANT_IT_TO_APPEAR
<div>
  <% image_tag 'image.png' %>
</div>  
PLACE_THE_EXAMPLE_CODE_BETWEEN_THESE_TWO_LINES_EXACTLY_AS_YOU_WANT_IT_TO_APPEAR
%-->
<!--%= "code = escape_the_erb_as_needed(%q{#{code}})" %-->
<% do_normal_erb_stuff %>
```

will do The Right Thing.

You'd need a helper to implement the `escape_the_erb_as_needed` functionality of course; a little experimentation should help you sort out what needs to be escape and in what way.

All that might look a bit complicated but it is really pretty straight forward. I've added custom template processing steps using Tilt and Sprockets and it turned out to be pretty simple in the end; figuring out which simple things to do took some work but I've already done that work for you:

1. `Tilt::Template` subclass, you get this by piggy backing on `Tilt::ErubisTemplate`.
2. Register with Tilt by calling `Tilt.register`.
3. Register with Sprockets by calling `Rails.application.assets.register_engine`.
4. ...
5. Profit.

Comment: What about the new lines for `%q{...}` ? When displayed, it is all on one line.

Comment: @oldergod: No it isn't, throw a `<pre>` around it and you'll see that it does the same thing as the heredoc as far as EOLs are concerned.