# Fully escaping a multiline erb segment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I'm trying to create a simple partial that allows me to display code blocks without going through weird contortions in my code.

So I did this in the partial:

```
<% lang ||= "" %>
<% language = "lang='#{lang}'" %>

<div class="codebox">
        <% if title %>
            <h3><%= title %></h3>
        <% end %>
    <pre <%= language %>><%=text.unindent%></pre>
</div>
```

And this in lib for unindenting strings (thanks to a very nice SO suggestion):

```
class String
    def unindent; gsub(/^#{scan(/^\s+/).min}/, "") end
end
```

Then, I can just do this, and get a very pretty little code box:

```
<%= render partial: 'pre', locals: { title: "example.html", lang: 'html', text: "
                <div class='cl' style='text-align:center'>
                  <div class='collapse-group'>
                        <!-- Title, always viewable --> 
                        <a class='bundle' href='#'>'Click here to expand'</a> 
                    <div class='collapse'>
                        <!-- The content to be hidden or shown -->
                    </div> 
                  </div>
                </div>
                "} %>
```

This turns into this:

[image]

Works like a charm, unless I put in a bunch of erb, in which case it goes nuts and starts erroring all over the place. Ex of an error-producer (contents not super relevant. I made sure that all quotes within are double, while the "string" is in single quotes):

```
<%= render partial: 'pre', locals: { title: "example.html", lang: 'html', text: '
                <% sub ||= "" %>
                <% term ||= "(expand)" %>
                <% style ||= "" %>

                <div class="cl" style="text-align:center">
                <div class="collapse-group">
                    <<%=tag%> class="squeeze" style=<%="#{style}"%>> 
                        <%=title%> 
                        <% if sub != "" %> 
                            <small><%= sub %></small>
                        <% end %>
                        <a class="bundle" href="#"><%= term %></a> 
                    </<%=tag%>>
                <div class="collapse">
                ' } %>
```

Any way I can just tell html that what I'm putting inside those quotes is 100% literal characters? I've tried individually escaping ">"s and ">"s and "%"s and all that, and it's a messy (and ineffectual) path I'm hoping not to go down.

EX of what I want the above to look like:

[image]

Comment: Why are you setting all that text in the view layer? It's not clear to me what you want escaped and what you don't, or why whatever it is you want escaped is being declared/initialized in a template.

Comment: Well, the idea is I'll be using lots of code boxes (sort of like the ones on SO), and I want to be able to basically just paste the code I want formatted and have it automatically formatted, which is what I have going for the first example above. It breaks with the ERB example. Is there some far better way of doing this that I don't know about? I'm definitely open to suggestions. EDIT -- gave an example of what I'm trying to accomplish neatly above.

Comment: If the text value will normally be coming from the DB, don't bother trying to test by filling out a template manually.

Comment: I DON'T want the ERB executed. I want everything inside the single quotes in that partial call to be printed to the screen as literal text. And it won't normally be coming from the DB. I'm just trying to come up with a way to more neatly and easily post with code blocks in the future.

Comment: I think you're out of luck unless you're up for [some shenanigans and chicanery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13261376/479863) or if you don't mind stuffing that text-with-ERB into a variable in your controller so that you can sneak it past Erubis.

Comment: Huh. So how do people usually do this? Any gems or anything? I found coderay, but that's just for coloring, right? Is there no easy way to do auto-escaped code segments? (By the way, just about to add, what I mean, to clarify my comment right above)

Comment: You could move your text-with-ERB into a variable (assigned in the controller) so that it will only go into the ERB files *after* the ERB has been parsed. If you insist on keeping it inlined then you have to play games with switching ERB delimiters (see the link in my earlier comment).

Comment: Did what you suggested (as a possibility) and moved the code into variables declared in the controller. Works great! Thanks. Only issue is the size of that file, now. Is there any way to avoid this becoming a HUGE controller as I add more and more code snippets? Thanks!

Comment: You can shuffle your code snippets around and put them in some sort of database (possibly even a static JSON, YAML, XML, or SQLite file). Using a database or flat file of some sort would let you do away with your prefix stripping as well.

Comment: Btw. you do know you can escape ERB tags with `<%% %%>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a nice approach in this would be to use [#capture](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture), for example in a helper (not tested, just a hint of what to do)  :

```
def code_block( title = nil, lang = nil, &block )
  output = capture( &block ) # this is the answer to all your problems
  output = output.unindent   # optional, escape it as you want, too
  # rendering a partial is still possible, 
  # but i'd recommend using an absolute path : 
  render partial: 'my_html_bits/code_block', 
         locals:  {title: title, lang: lang, text: output }
end
```

then you could do :

```
<%= code_block( 'example.html', 'html' ) do %>
  <%# whatever code here will be captured %>
  <p>Even plain old html.</p>
<% end %>
```

**As a side note :**

- your `#unindent` method more or less mimicks an existing ActiveSupport monkey-patch on `String`, [#strip_heredoc](http://apidock.com/rails/String/strip_heredoc)
- in those cases, using [#content_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) can also save you a lot of hassle, i.e :

  ```
  <<%=tag%> class="squeeze" style=<%="#{style}"%>>
  # more code...
  ```

  could become :

  ```
  <%= content_tag tag, class: 'squeeze', style: style do %>
  # more code...
  ```