# Put <% as a literal in an .erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Let's say I want to display in an erb page a hint on how to write erb:

in helpfile.html.erb:

```
Here's the right way to write a basic erb statement: <%= a = 1 %>
```

The problem is that when that erb file is processed as a view in rails, the literal erb `<%=` gets interpreted and so in the file displayed I just see

```
Here's the right way to write a basic erb statement: 1
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Here is an answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322413/how-do-i-escape-erb-code-in-fixtures

Comment: or maybe, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13261376/525478, depending on your use-case

Answer (score 2):

You could either write it as:

```
Here's the right way to write a basic erb statement: <%= '<%= a = 1 %>' %>
```

Or perhaps as:

```
Here's the right way to write a basic erb statement: &lt;%= a = 1 %&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using an entity:

```
<&#37;= Here's the right way to write a basic erb statement: 1 &#37;>
```

Comment: No love for `&lt;` and `&gt;` for those of us that haven't memorized the ASCII table?